# How to prevent code execution in ipython when autoreload fails?

Tags: python, ipython

In ipython, I have turned on autoreload in my configuration file.  Normally this picks up any changes in my code and ipython will execute the newly compiled version.  However, if there is a syntax error in the code, I get the old version instead.  Sometimes it's not obvious that this has occurred, which is very confusing.  How can I prevent the code from rerunning when there's an error during autoreload?  Alternatively, how can I make it more obvious that such an error has occurred?

Example: consider this script

```
from __future__ import print_function

def do():
    for i in xrange(50):
        print('lines that obscure the view')
    print()

    print('Old version')
```

I invoke this with

```
In [1]: import junk

In [2]: junk.do()
```

which generates

```
...
lines that obscure the view
lines that obscure the view
Old version
```

Now change it to this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def do():
    for i in xrange(50):
        print('lines that obscure the view')
    print()

    # print('Old version')

    a = 3 * 
    print('New version')
```

Upon rerunning the code, the autoreload will generate a syntax error, then ipython will quickly generate output that scrolls the error off the screen.

```
...
lines that obscure the view
lines that obscure the view
Old version
```

I'm using python 2.7.12 and ipython 5.1.0.

Comment: Does your `import junk` not fail with an error ?

Comment: The initial import is of the old, valid code, so it succeeds.